# Copy & paste between Windows and Mac when using VNC

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop, copy-paste

I enabled screen sharing on my Mac with macOS Catalina (10.15.6). Now I'm accessing the Mac with VNC Viewer 6.20.529 (RealVNC) on my Windows 10 machine. These are the problems I have:

- slowlness even on LAN (e.g. right click needs ages to load the whole window, whole session needs sometimes seconds to refresh)
- can't transfer files (file transfer button is disabled/not supported)
- keyboard problems because differences in Mac and Windows and also because of the keyboard layout not being English and VNC is behaving differently
- and the biggest issue currently: can't use copy & paste between Mac and Windows

I didn't find some useful tips on the internet or on the Stackexchange sites. Am I missing a configuration? Or is the only solution to use another remote viewer/controller software?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with copy/paste using VNC Viewer from Windows to MacOS. It looks like you have to pay for VNC Server to get it working.

Instead I moved to Chrome Remote Desktop (so this doesn't answer the specific question, but is too long for comments). There seem to be two issues with this - one fixable and one not.

The issue I couldn't fix was that you will see a Window with "Your desktop is currently shared with...". I dragged this to the bottom right of the screen to hide it as much as possible, but you have to repeat this with every restart.

The second issue is that (obviously) the Windows key does not map to the Command key. This is "fixed" by choosing another key under "Configure key mappings". I chose to map ControlLeft to MetaLeft, and so then Ctl-C and Ctl-V (etc) worked fine.

Chrome Remote Desktop also solves one of your other issues - you can transfer files (although I have not used).